# Transformando esse código legível pra Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá queria saber como transformo esse código legível pra roda no Python 3`

```
import urllib

proxy = {'http': 'http://myproxy:port'}
print ("Using HTTP proxy %s" % proxy['http'])
urllib.urlopen('https://google.com', proxies=proxy).read()
f = urllib.urlopen('https://drrr.com', proxies=proxy).read()
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui vai um exemplo de como usar `urllib` em Python 3 com os requisitos que você tem:

```
from urllib.request import URLopener
proxy = {'http': 'http://myproxy:port'}
urlopener = URLopener(proxy)
content = urlopener.open('https://mywebsite.com').read()
print(content)
```